# Json like object in path params in Express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

The requirement is to have object structure in received params from req object in the express.

For example:
`/users/items[\:]id-:id/items[\:]type-:type`

In this, I get below value in `req.params`

```
{
  id: 1,
  type: 'general'
}
```

when called with `/users/items:id-1/items:type-general`

Is there any way to get it like below:

```
{
  items:{
    id: 1,
    type: 'general'
  }
}
```

*EDIT*

Another sample route to support:  `/users/items:id-1/boxes:type-general`

```
{
  items:{
    id: 1,
  },
  boxes:{
    type: 'general'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like.

```
app.param(['id', 'type'], (req, res, next, value, key) => {
  req.params.items = req.params.items ? req.params.items : {};
  req.params.items[key] = value;
  // Removing the default properties which gets added.
  delete req.params[key];
  next();
});
```

This would help you make changes to a key in req.params.

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.param

[or]

The other way is to use a middleware, with respect to your edited question. You can try something like

```
const getParamsAsJSONObject = (req, res, next) => {
  const [emptypart, ...parts] = req.url.split('/');
  console.log(parts);
  req.customParams = parts.reduce((paramsObj, currentPart) => {
    console.log(paramsObj);
    console.log(currentPart);
    const [parentKey, childKeyValue] = currentPart.split(':');
    paramsObj[parentKey] = paramsObj[parentKey] ? paramsObj[parentKey] : {};   
    const [childKey, childValue] = childKeyValue.split('-');
    paramsObj[parentKey][childKey] = childValue;
    return paramsObj;
  }, {});
  next();
};

app.use('/users', getParamsAsJSONObject, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.customParams);
  // Remaining Piece of the code to be added.
});
```

Comment: Hmm... I thought of adding such middleware in between, but the issue with such middleware is that the object key (here `items`) is also dynamic based on the route. Some routes will have items, some will have nominees, some will have users, etc..

Comment: Edited the question to explain better, please check.